# Save checkbox position/value in Adapter

Tags: java, android

I have a custom ListView that contains a textview and checkbox. The user can select only one checkbox at the time. I was able to hold it with SharedPrefrences when the user pressed back button, but, the problem is, I can't figure out how to retrieve which checkbox was selected in Adapter once the user comes back to main Activity.

I feel like everything should be done in Adapter, to retrieve it, right ?

I'm not sure if I explained it right, tell me if you need more information.

```
package company.tuyu.tuyu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListAdapterUserBooking extends ArrayAdapter<Bookings> {

private Bookings bookings;

private TextView user_book_total;

private static final String PREFERENCES_NAMESPACE = "checkboxes_states";

int selected_position = -1;

public ListAdapterUserBooking(Context context, ArrayList<Bookings> bookings) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_user_bookinglistview, bookings);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    bookings = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from((getContext()));

    View customView = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_user_bookinglistview, parent, false);

    final TextView serviceName = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.custom_user_booking_serviceName);
    TextView servicePrice = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.custom_user_booking_servicePrice);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.custom_user_booking_checkBox);

    user_book_total = (TextView) ((Activity) getContext()).findViewById(R.id.user_book_total);

    serviceName.setText(bookings.serviceName[position]);
    servicePrice.setText("£" + bookings.servicePrice[position]);

    checkBox.setChecked(position == selected_position);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAMESPACE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bookings.totalPrice = bookings.servicePrice[position];

            final boolean isChecked = checkBox.isChecked();
            if (isChecked) {
                selected_position = position;

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("checkBoxChecked", true);
                editor.apply();

                bookings.selectedServiceID = bookings.ID[position];
                bookings.selectedServicePrice = bookings.servicePrice[position];

                user_book_total.setText("£" + bookings.totalPrice);
            } else {
                selected_position = -1;

                user_book_total.setText("£" + "0" + ".00");
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return customView;
    }
}
```

Comment: selected_position should to the job. What is the problem with that?

Comment: How do I retrieve saved checkbox once the Activity starts ?

Comment: Why can't you just query the shared_prefs from your main activity again to read the selected item?

Comment: @Capricorn and how would I set the checkbox to checked from main activity ?

Comment: It's not your main activities job to set the checkbox state to select in your list of items/checkboxes. That's the job of your adapter. You might be missing some basics about [Android Adapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) (hint: maybe pass the "currently" selected Booking into the adapter, the adapter decides which checkbox view to check).

Comment: Ty for the hint, but what confuses me is how can I tell the position of checkbox when there are no actually positions. I mean, if I have a variable like int "currentlySelected" checkbox, and how would I pass it to Adapter.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. Save the `serviceName` when item is checked, and check for the name before you display again. `editor.putString("serviceName", serviceName)` to save the selected service. You must save the `serviceName` because `position` is liable to change.

Comment: @user8035311 yeah, sorry posting the answer down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue myself, but forgot to post the fix, here is what I did:

```
package company.tuyu.tuyu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListAdapterUserBooking extends ArrayAdapter<Bookings> {

private Bookings bookings;

private TextView user_book_total;

int selected_position = -1;

public ListAdapterUserBooking(Context context, ArrayList<Bookings> bookings) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_user_bookinglistview, bookings);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    bookings = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from((getContext()));

    View customView = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_user_bookinglistview, parent, false);

    final TextView serviceName = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.custom_user_booking_serviceName);
    TextView servicePrice = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.custom_user_booking_servicePrice);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.custom_user_booking_checkBox);

    user_book_total = (TextView) ((Activity) getContext()).findViewById(R.id.user_book_total);

    serviceName.setText(bookings.serviceName[position]);
    servicePrice.setText("£" + bookings.servicePrice[position]);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    selected_position = sharedPreferences.getInt("selectedPosition", 0);
    checkBox.setChecked(selected_position == position);

    bookings.totalPrice = bookings.servicePrice[selected_position];
    bookings.selectedServiceID = bookings.ID[selected_position];
    bookings.selectedServicePrice = bookings.servicePrice[selected_position];

    user_book_total.setText("£" + bookings.totalPrice);

    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bookings.totalPrice = bookings.servicePrice[position];

            final boolean isChecked = checkBox.isChecked();
            if (isChecked) {
                selected_position = position;

                bookings.selectedServiceID = bookings.ID[position];
                bookings.selectedServicePrice = bookings.servicePrice[position];

                user_book_total.setText("£" + bookings.totalPrice);
            } else {
                selected_position = -1;

                user_book_total.setText("£" + "0" + ".00");
            }

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("selectedPosition", selected_position);
            editor.apply();

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return customView;
    }
}
```